# Why am I not able to import Semantic into react component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, semantic-ui

I get this error when importing semantic > Can't resolve 'semantic-ui-react' <
(i've installed semantic and did gulp build and all that)

I tried this

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const ButtonExampleButton = () => (
  <Button>Click Here</Button>
)

export default ButtonExampleButton
```

Comment: are you sure you installed `semantic-ui-react` and not `semantic-ui`?

Comment: i did this npm install semantic-ui --save @Sagivb.g

Comment: did you have gulp installed ?

Comment: I installed gulp and did gulp build in the /semantic folder and it all went fine from my view @javed

Comment: @AbdirizakObsiye check this, the lib that you are using is this one: https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage, so install it using `$ npm install semantic-ui-react`

Comment: @AbdirizakObsiye  npm install -g gulp try to install gulp globally. because it must for semantic ui

Comment: @MayankShukla thanks. So the guide was different to the example code. I'll try that

Comment: @AbdirizakObsiye this is not the same library. for react components you need to install  `semantic-ui-react`

Comment: @Sagivb.g It's working now except there's no styling on the button from what i see using the same code.

Comment: This library doesn't provide the css library, only the react components. You would need to include the css library as well. Via a cdn link or an npm package. See the [docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage#css)

Comment: IT WORKS!! write it down as an answer and i will give you a tick @Sagivb.g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the react components of semantic ui, you will need to install the [semantic-ui-react library](https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction).
Note that this library doesn't include the `CSS` files of [semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/) and you will need to include it yourself.

Either via a `CDN` or a npm package. See the [docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage#css) for examples.